# PHP: make sessions from database

Tags: php, session, pdo

I am trying to make some sessions from my database. 
What I wan't to do is, take a specific row in my database an add the value of each column to a session. 
The name of the session should then be the name of the column. 
I am running ´session_start();´
Here is the code and my attempt to do it:

```
function opponent_data(){
    try {
        $PDO_new = new PDO("mysql:host=" . DB_HOST . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
        $PDO_new->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $opponent = $PDO_new->prepare("SELECT * FROM Info WHERE  user_name =:username");
        $opponent->bindParam(":username",  $_SESSION["opponent"]);
        $opponent->execute();

        //my failed attempt
        $row = $opponent->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $column = $opponent->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
        $col_count = $opponent->columnCount();
        for ($x = 0; $x <= $col_count; $x++) {
            $_SESSION[$column[$x]] = $row[$x];
        }

    }catch (PDOException $e) {
        $error[] = $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help. 
Sorry for the bad tittle, I didn't knew what i should call this.

Comment: are you already using `session_start()` somewhere?

Comment: ah yes I am, sorry forgot to say that.
Just added it in the description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `PDO::FETCH_COLUMN` a column number is expected ie.:

```
$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, $number_of_column);
```

It would be easier to loop through the columns from your `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`

```
$row = $opponent->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($row as $columnName => $columnVal){

     $_SESSION[$columnName] =$columnVal;

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

`$x` is a number... But you are fetching your result into an associative array. `$row[$x]` subsequently does not exist.

`fetchColumn()` and `fetchAssoc()` returns only 1 column... These should be in while-loops...

Comment: Thanks for explaining what i did wrong. But i will give @andrew the answer as he also solved my problem.